# php date_create showing incorrect year

Tags: php

I am using date_create to create a date object. I realized when I ran this code

```
$date=date_create("7 December, 2017");
echo date_format($date,"Y/m/d");
```

it outputs this:

```
2018/12/07
```

The year is wrong. What's the way to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

=> Try this code ..

```
<?php
     $date=date_create("7 December 2017");
     echo date_format($date,"Y/m/d");
?>
```

**Error in Format**

for more info check http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php

Answer (score 2):

If you use default date_create() function you must remove the comma after the month. But if you need to parse the input with the comma or any other format you can use [date_create_from_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-create-from-format.php) instead.

```
$date = date_create_from_format('d M, Y', '7 December, 2017');
echo date_format($date,"Y/m/d");
```

The output will be as expected

```
2017/12/07
```